# Plot a simple table of data

Tags: python, dataframe, plot

I have a really simple table of data that I am trying to plot, but for some reason I can see how to do this. I was trying to create a bar for each log type (plugin and audit) side by sid as my Y cords, then the x would be each environment. But for some reason, everything I try fails. I don't have a lot of experiance working with visuals in Python, so I thought I would reach out.

```
    Plugin Logs Audit Logs  Env
0   73505       1453072     DEV
1   729911      5284038     UAT
2   140331      15701874    STG
3   16975948    358738645   PRD
```

I am counting records in two differnt logs in four different environments to identify when to have them purged. These are just simple counts. The 359 million logs in PRD seems problematic. I thought a visual would be helpful.

Below is what I was trying to do, but it fails. I know I am not sending in the Env column. I couldn't get any of this to work with single histograms or simple bar plots either. I tried about a dozen different things but nothing is working. I suspect I am missing something really simple here. Below is the sort of approach I have been trying to get to work.

Any thoughts, suggestions, or examples would be much appreicated.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df_test = pd.read_json('{"Plugin-Trace Logs":{"0":73505,"1":729911,"2":140331,"3":16975948},"Audit Logs":{"0":1453072,"1":5284038,"2":15701874,"3":358738645},"Env":{"0":"DEV","1":"UAT","2":"STG","3":"PRD"}}')

def plot_histograms(df, col):
    plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
    df['Audit Logs'].hist(alpha=0.3, color='blue', bins=4, label='Audit Logs')
    df['Plugin-Trace Logs'].hist(alpha=0.3, color='red', bins=4, label='Plugin-Trace Logs')    
    plt.legend()
    plt.xlabel(col)
    plt.ylabel('Count')
    
plot_histograms(df_test, 'Environments')
```

[image]

Comment: "but it fails", "nothing is working"...What _specifically_ is wrong with your attempts? Is there no output? Is there an error message? Is the output incorrect or not what you expect? Please [edit] and describe the expected vs actual behavior to make a [mcve] so that we can better understand how to help

Comment: Thanks. I updated the original post to include and image and I dumped the dataframe to JSON and just load it in the sample. So if you run that sample, it will create what I am seeing. I am open to other suggestions and I am not stuck on this plot. If there are better options, I'd be interested.

Comment: The plot is just plotting the count of the number of records and it is nesting the second histogram into the first bar in the first histogram. This is only one of about two dozen different things I have tried and it's the cloest to what I am trying to do. Now, if I can just pull the second plot out of the first one, and have it plot the data and not the count, then place the side by side or one over the other, that is what I want to do.

Comment: Well, it's a histogram, so I see that is what is causing it to use the count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can try this :

```
sns.set_style("darkgrid")

def plot_bars(df, col):
    ax = df.plot.bar(figsize=(10,6), color=["red", "blue"])
    ax.set_xlabel(col)
    ax.set_ylabel("Count")
    ax.set_xticklabels(df[col])
    ax.set_yscale("log") # <-- optional
    ax.legend(["Plugin-Trace Logs", "Audit Logs"])
    plt.show()

plot_bars(df_test, "Env")
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice! This is what I was trying to do. Adding the log is helpful. I was wondering what to do with the significant scale. Log works great.

Comment: But what I don't get is how I could have figure this one out on my own. Since I am pretty new to Python, only been using it here and there the past year or so, I don't see how I would have thought this one through unless I had happened to find an example. I guess I need to go over dataframe.plot.bar? But thanks for posting this and answer my question. It's very much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, *side-by-side* bars and graphs in general are described here : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html#bar-plots